# Sorting an ArrayList of mixed integers and strings while preserving relative ordering of strings and integers

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, arraylist

Consider an arraylist as given below

```
unsortedList = {6,"ball",3,1,"apple","cat",4}
```

this needs to be sorted to

```
sortedList = {1,"apple",3,4,"ball","cat",6}
```

Sort the strings alphabetically. Sort the numbers in ascending.  But note the following condition:

- Wherever an integer is there in the unsorted list, it must be an integer in the sorted list.
- Wherever a string is there in the unsorted list, it must be a string in the sorted list.

Notice that in the above example, all the integers are sorted ascending and all the strings are sorted ascending, but the relative positions of integers and strings is unchanged from before.

Comment: I'm having difficulty figuring out the sorting criteria.

Comment: What makes "apple" > 1 and "ball" > 4 ?

Comment: @jterrace Nothing. He just wants to keep integers on the same position as in the unsorted list (same with strings). Then sort integers vs integers and strings vs strings.

Comment: Suggestion: Split it in Integer/String lists, sort both of them, re-combine them to new list according to the types in the original list (`LinkedList#poll` is good for that).

Comment: I see... the data type order must be preserved.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 8):

One option here is to do the following:

- Create a new list of all the integers in the original list.
- Create a new list of all the strings in the original list.
- Sort each list.
- Iterate over the original list, doing the following:

  - If the element there is an integer, write back the next unwritten integer from the sorted integer list.
  - If the element there is a string, write back the next unwritten string from the sorted string list.

This is quite efficient - you just need to do two sorts.  Here's some code for it:

```
public void relativeOrderSort(List<Object> list) {
    /* Create a list of just the integers and just the strings
     * from the original list.
     */
    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Object obj: list) {
        if (obj instanceof Integer) {
            intList.add((Integer) obj);
        } else if (obj instanceof String) {
            strList.add((String) obj);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("List has a non-int, non-string member.");
        }
    }

    /* Sort the lists. */
    Collections.sort(intList);
    Collections.sort(strList);

    /* Merge the lists back together. */
    int intIndex = 0, strIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i) instanceof Integer) {
           list.set(i, intList.get(intIndex++));
        } else {
           list.set(i, strList.get(strIndex++));
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect.I was missing the reference back to original list while merging the sorted lists.

Comment: Same solution with diff that input/output should be an arrays was called "Not an elegant" by interviewer. I am wonder does anybody know "elegant" one?

Comment: I will answer to my question.... Modified MergeSort could be used. In that case you won't be needed for additional N space.

Comment: @AliakseiYatsau A traditional implementation of merge sort uses linear auxiliary storage space to hold the elements during the merge. Would that add anything new from a complexity perspective?

Comment: @templatetypedef I don't know exactly how is it implemented in real world. I have one idea. It's not in-place merge idea but at least something that could be done at interview is to have auxiliary storage but smaller and when it's full shift array. Alg complexity still will be NlogN but it will add additional processing(shifting). I don't think it's more "elegant" then original version but to say the truth I run out of "elegant" ideas...

Answer (score 3):

Pseudo code:

```
Create a list of the indices pointing to integers ({0,2,3,6} in your case - indxInt )
Sort the integers  ({6,3,1,4} turns into {1,3,4,6})
Put them back at the locations given by the pointers:
  sorted(indxInt(0)) = 1;
  sorted(indxInt(1)) = 3;
  sorted(3) = 4; // indxInt(2) == 3
  sorted(6) = 6; // indxInt(3) == 6
Repeat for the strings
```